# Disable click on tab. Want to stop switching of tab by clicking on the tab

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple tabs like this

```
<md-tabs md-selected="selectedTab()">
    <md-tab label="General"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Type"></md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Details"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

I have buttons which controls the selectedIndex of the tab. So I want to disable the click(i.e switching of tab by clicking on the tab).

What attribute should I used in md-tabs/ md-tab to disable click event on the tab?

Here is the error if I click on the tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<element ng-disabled="expression returning a truthy value">
```

you can hard code in 'true' if you want to permanently disable the element.

This should make it still visible but grayed out and un-clickable.